# How to grab those console messages and sent in the mail message

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have module which is invoking a stored procedure from the vb.net console application like this. This stored procedure has lot of print statements in it. When I execute this console application, it will display messages in the console. I want to grab those messages and send through a mail

```
Dim Con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SaveReceiptsFromFile_GFF", Con)

Try
   Using Con
      Con.Open()

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

   End Using
Catch ex As SqlException
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

   sendmailwhenfail()
End Try
Con.Close()
```

My module for sending mail is like this :

```
Public Shared Sub sendmailwhenfail()
        Try
            Dim AnEmailMessage As New MailMessage
            AnEmailMessage.From = New MailAddress("tester@gmail.com")
            AnEmailMessage.To.Add("mymail@xxxxx.com")
            AnEmailMessage.Subject = "this is test subject"
            AnEmailMessage.Body = "this is test body"
            AnEmailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High
            Dim SimpleSMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            With SimpleSMTP
                .Port = 587
                .EnableSsl = True
                .Credentials = _
                New NetworkCredential("tester@gmail.com", "Tester123")
                .Send(AnEmailMessage)
            End With
            MsgBox("Email sent")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Everything is working fine when fail, My question is, how to grab those console messages and sent in the mail message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the same Exception ex.Message, ex.Source and use it as parameters for your method sendmailwhenfail(), for example:

```
try
{
    // do your thing
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline(String.Format("{0} :: {1}", ex.Source, ex.Message));
    SendMail(ex.Source, ex.Message);
}
```

so, whatever the error message is in the exception will also be passed onto the SendMail method.

Comment: my sendmailwhenfail() is not having any arguments though